# Batch file to check website status from a text file and restart service based on string

Tags: parsing, batch-file

I need some batch guru to assist me in getting this resolved. I have a couple of files via which we are monitoring the response from the websites using wget. When the site is down we  get the following response code in test1.txt:

```
Connecting to 10.x.x.x:443... failed: Bad file descriptor.
```

whilst when the site is running the response code in test2.txt is

```
Connecting to 10.x.x.x:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I do not see any common pattern in both the above outputs based on which I can form a logic. Need some assistance in determining if from the outputs above

- if the website is running, do nothing
- if the website is down, start service.

Note, we need to do this only on the basis of the output from these files.

Tried the provided solution but it didn't work:

```
TestScript>wget-1.14.exe --spider --no-check-certificate https://somesite   | find "Bad file descriptor"  1>nul
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2015-10-08 18:15:21--  https://somesite
Connecting to 10.x.x.x:443... failed: Bad file descriptor.
TestScript>if errorlevel 1 (echo site is up )  else (echo site is down )
site is up
```

Comment: there's no `2>&1` in your command line and I even added an explanation why it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the output of `wget` to `find` to look for `Bad file descriptor` and then use `errorlevel`:

```
wget --spider http://someurl 2>&1 | find "Bad file descriptor" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo site is up
) else (
    echo site is down
)
```

- `2>&1` redirects the messages into the standard output so that it can be piped
- `--spider` makes wget only check the url without saving the result

Alternatively use the file you already have:

```
if exist test1.txt find "Bad file descriptor" test1.txt >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (echo start the service)
```

Comment: My bad, I might have missed it in a haste. Thanks much, it solved the purpose.